# modbus4j modbusRTU master and slave communication function

Tags: java, modbus

suddenly i have download seroUtils.jar and modbus4J.jar files and include it into netbeans. So please suggest me some methods to send data to slave and receive data from slave through rs232 cable . In my program i have set serial parameters. But i dont know how to send data and receive command from slave device.

Please suggest me some methods or tutorial for serial programming in modbus4j.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a similar project and I am using rxtx. They have neat explanations and sample programs and it is quite popular as well. Here are some links you might find useful

sample projects:-
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Projects

FAQs:-
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ

Download:-
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

Guide:-
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Using_RXTX